# Persistence of boost multi_index_container stored in a file

Tags: c++, boost, mmap, boost-interprocess, boost-multi-index

Can I rely on boost multi_index_container allocated within memory mapped file? Will be this kind of "database" portable between computers with the same endianess?

Comment: This sounds extremely platform specific, as the C++ standard lacks the concept of "memory mapped file" as far as I know.  :).  The concern I would have would be "would it be at the same base address each time?", and I would doubt it.

Comment: Yes. As far as i understand how mmap or its boost wrapper works I will get always the same base address (0 or provided offset).

Comment: I'm talking about the offset in memory, not the offset in the file.  In the boost case, you are allowed to pass a hint: `mapped_file_params::hint`, but it is only a hint.  So no, this is not safe.

Comment: And allocator designed for memory mapped files won't take care of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not safe.  The address of the first byte in the memory mapped file cannot be guaranteed to be the same between invocations.

Boost's memory mapped file takes a `hint`, but it is only a hint.

So in the first invocation, the memory might be located at `0xBAADF00D`.  On the second invocation, it might be located at `0xF00DBAAD`.  Pointers within the structure would no longer be valid, as they would point to memory around `0xBAADF00D` rather than around `0xF00DBAAD`.

As a serious problem, it might *usually* work in testing, as the `hint` might usually be obeyed -- but sometimes there will already be stuff at that memory address, and the `hint` will have to be ignored.

(There are other parts that make this really hard -- but the above makes it pretty infeasible).

Now, strategies like this can work, but require very intrusive introspection of the data structures in question.  You'd have to do a pass like DLL readdressing in order to get the data structures to have the correct offsets, and by that point you might as well just serialize it flat.

Comment: I'm basing on this example:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/multi_index/example/ip_allocator.cpp

namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
bip::allocator<char,bip::managed_mapped_file::segment_manager>

won't take car of allocating strings, vectors and so on?

Comment: @Dejwi Sure, the stuff is allocated with offsets in the memory mapped file.  But then it is saved to disk.  Then, someone else loads it at a *different* offset.  What happens?  Examine a really simple case: an `int*` pointing to an `int` within the file, which is mapped to `0xBAADF00D`.  In the original case, what happens when you dereference the `int*`?  Now, the file is loaded with base address `0xF00DBAAD` -- what happens?

Comment: The offset problem can be overcome without readdressing or anything by resorting to data structures that use [offset pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost/interprocess/offset_ptr.html) rather than regular ones: Boost.MultiIndex is prepared to do so.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of [Boost.Interprocess's memory mapped files](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.mapped_file) and a little care you can persist `multi_index_container`s; the problem of mappings being located at different addresses can be overcome using [*offsets*](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost/interprocess/offset_ptr.html) rather than pointers, and Boost.MultiIndex is prepared to handle that: see [this example](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/examples.html#example12) where a sort of simplistic database is implemented with access from several processes at a time.

This said, using memory mapped files for persistence is an extremely fragile approach, as it will only work if these parameters are the exactly the same:

- machine architecture
- operating system version
- compiler version
- compilation parameters (which might affect padding, for instance)
- version of all relevant libs used (Boost included), as ABIs might change across versions
- some other aspects I forgot about :-)

Everything considered, using Boost.Serialization as suggested by @alfC is probably the best solution for *portable* persistence across different environments. If you're concerned about speed, a mixed approach like this might work:

- When in session and within the context of several processes (ideally, out of the same executable) using the same structure in the same machine, memory-map the container.
- Once the session is finished (or every so often to guard against crashes etc.), portably persist using Boost.Serialization.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to transport a `multi_index` from one computer to another the best thing is to use Boost.Serialization, which works out of the box:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/creation.html#serialization

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <fstream>
...
void save(const employee_set& es)
{
  std::ofstream ofs("data");
  boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
  oa<<es;
}

void load(employee_set& es)
{
  std::ifstream ifs("data");
  boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
  ia>>es;
}
...
employee_set es; // a multi_index type
... // fill it with data
save(es);
...
employee_set restored_es;
load(restored_es);
```